# CSF Firewall: how to block IPs without restarting CSF

Tags: cpanel, block, firewall, whm

How can I dynamically (programatically) block IP addresses using Config Server Security & Firewall?

I am on Centos (linux) with cPanel & WHM

Answer (score 5):

You can deny an ip in csf as below but need to refresh csf because every service apply changes after restart or refresh.

Deny IP

> csf -d IPaddress

Refresh:

> csf -r

Comment: You can also add the entry to `/etc/csf/csf.deny` and then execute `csf -r`.

Comment: He told u that without restarting CSF

Answer (score 0):

> how to block IPs without restarting CSF

Restarting csf by csf -r is not an big deal. You don't need to do any precautions to do this. So blocking IP with or with out csf restart is of same effect.

csf works along with iptables so for denying IP you can use  "csf -d IP" instead of writing iptable rules.

csf eases the firewall works. :)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here appear to be out of date now. It is no longer necessary to reload CSF after blocking an IP address. Here is some example output:

```
sudo csf -d 10.0.0.1 do not delete

Adding 10.0.0.1 to csf.deny and iptables DROP...
DROP  all opt -- in !lo out *  10.0.0.1  -> 0.0.0.0/0  
LOGDROPOUT  all opt -- in * out !lo  0.0.0.0/0  -> 10.0.0.1
```

And [here is a thread on the CSF forum](https://forum.configserver.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=10248) confirming it.

Comment: Fwiw, I checked out that thread and have done some experimenting. I'm on version `v13.08 (cPanel)`, and `csf -d` is not sufficient for the rule to be active. On my system, subsequently running `csf -r` is required for the rule to be activated. I'm not a CSF/iptables expert, though, so maybe I'm overlooking something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested blocking few IPs without restarting and it works. You only need to restart if you remove IP from csf.deny eg:

```
csf -dr 1.1.1.1
csf -r
```